Can I use linearHypothesis from the car package with fixest models?
I have used feols from package fixest to run a regression and I want to test if my coefficient is equal to some value (in my case, equal to 1). Can I use linearHypothesis command from package car to test?
I have tried the following:
linearHypothesis(reg1[[1]],"m_s = 1")

(where reg1 is a list of fixest objects). I did not get a F-statistic, but a Chisq one. See the results:
Linear hypothesis test

Hypothesis:
m_s = 1

Model 1: restricted model
Model 2: f_n_m_t_m - f_n ~ 1 + m_s

  Res.Df Df  Chisq Pr(>Chisq)    
1    255                         
2    254  1 19.749  8.832e-06 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Is this right?
I would like any help.

The answer is yes, what you are doing is coded right.
Though there is no linearHypothesis.fixest method, according to the documentation,

The default method will work with any model object for which the coefficient vector can be retrieved by coef and the coefficient-covariance matrix by vcov (otherwise the argument vcov. has to be set explicitly).

Reproducible example:
library(fixest)
library(car)
#> Loading required package: carData

res <- feols(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length | Species, iris)
class(res)
#> [1] "fixest"

coef(res)
#>  Sepal.Width Petal.Length 
#>    0.4322172    0.7756295
vcov(res)
#>              Sepal.Width Petal.Length
#> Sepal.Width   0.02602035  -0.01390552
#> Petal.Length -0.01390552   0.01601377

Created on 2024-10-22 with reprex v2.1.1
Both coef.fixest and vcov.fixest exist, so linearHypothesis(res) should work.
library(fixest)
library(car)
#> Loading required package: carData

res <- feols(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length | Species, iris)
linearHypothesis(res, "Sepal.Width = 0")
#> 
#> Linear hypothesis test:
#> Sepal.Width = 0
#> 
#> Model 1: restricted model
#> Model 2: Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length | Species
#> 
#>   Res.Df Df  Chisq Pr(>Chisq)   
#> 1    146                        
#> 2    145  1 7.1794   0.007374 **
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

Created on 2024-10-22 with reprex v2.1.1
